# Testing if a BG will Repeat Tile Properly in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, background, tiles

I am frequently working to create background textures in Photoshop to be used on the web. Unfortunately I usually have to guess, or just use freebies from other websites.

I would like to build my own textures in Photoshop and check if they tile properly *before* exporting the image. Is there a way to do this quickly? I remember a method using offset, but I'm not familiar with the tools.

Below are a couple example background tiles so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image: tile1]

[image: tile2]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- create your image. For example, let's say it's 200px square
- go to FILTERS > OTHER > OFFSET and type in x and y numbers that are half your image size (in this case 100px)
- this will shift your image over that many pixels and put the pixels that were moved off the canvas on to the other side. You now will see a seam running down the middle of your image where the pattern doesn't quite repeat fully.
- touch up this seam to make it a smooth blend using whichever tools you like (clone tool is a common option).
- save your new image.

For more complex images, you may need to do a final offset of say 1/4 the pixel dimensions to touch up the edges you might have missed the first time that fell near the edge of the canvas.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

DA01 answers how to make it but your question is how to test it. The answer to that question is:

1. Select your pattern layer
2. Edit > Define Pattern
3. Create New Layer
4. Select All
5. Edit > Fill > Pattern > Choose your pattern
6. Hit okay and see if it looks good

Comment: ugh. I totally misread the question! Good tip. Another option is to simply make a test HTML file with a repeating background. Then just keep re-saving the file and reloading the browser.

Comment: Yes I knew how to do it in HTML/CSS but wasn't aware that Photoshop could test as well. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

I traditionally save the image as a jpg or png and then use basic html to test the tiling.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background: url(image.jpg) repeat 0 0;">
</body>
</html>
```

Open that in a browser and you can see the tiling and simply re-save "image.jpg" and refresh the web page to check revisions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to do this, but the limit is that all the other patterns must be of the same size you will see why.

**Steps:**

- Make a 200px by 200px box.
- Convert it into an smart object.
- Duplicate and align it so there are 3 boxes horizontally. Make sure
  no overlapping or spaces in between.
- Duplicate the three boxes selected into 3 vertical columns.
- If not already enabled, enable floating windows in Preference.
- Double click and open the smart object.
- Align both windows as so that you can see both files.
- Fill the smart object with whatever pattern you want and see it in
  action in other window simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great (freeware for personal use) tool called [AMP Tile Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/TileViewer.php) that lets you very quickly check whether an image is tileable and how it will look tiled. I use it all the time and it works just great. No need to make patterns in Photoshop you will never use or have to delete afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Chrome extension called [Tile View](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tile-view/ajcjkemninihecbgljahanflndoeggao) that lets you right click an image and see how it tiles.

Comment: There is also this web-based tool I found out recently: http://tile.toyls.com/

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is just save the tile as a jpg and set it to tile on my desktop. Pretty quick and easy.