# How to slice this pattern for HTML/CSS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I want to slice this element:

[image]

So it's only, for example, 20 x 20 px. I can't do this normally; if I slice this image, and repeat it then I do not have a beautiful background.

How can I slice it so, that in future, when I put this as a background in CSS it looks like it is a big image, without any repeating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing if a BG will Repeat Tile Properly in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7033/testing-if-a-bg-will-repeat-tile-properly-in-photoshop). Its answers address how to accomplish what you're looking for. Here is [another example](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/creating-a-pattern-from-an-image/). If you read through it you'll note that you use offset to see where it needs to be cleaned up, and then you clean up the edges

Comment: Google 'create repeating pattern in Photoshop' for a pile of tutorials.

Comment: Can't you use the whole image? It seems small enough to me, we're not in the nineties anymore...

Comment: The image is 180k when saved as png-8. :P

Comment: An image like this shouldn't be saved as a PNG, but as a JPG.

Comment: Make a seamless tile out of it. you can find many easy tutorials for how to do that.